# Is there any way to copy file present at my local machine to remote Linux only by command line?

Tags: linux

I want to copy a file present on my local directory i.e. C:\Users\karansha\Desktop\Backup\sj1slm612\express_13000\config.xml

to remote linux machine directory : /apps/configuration/

I tried command using putty but it says No such file or directory :

```
scp C:\Users\karansha\Desktop\Backup\sj1slm612\express_13000\standalone-full.xml /apps/instances/express_13000/configuration/
```

Comment: You missed the destination. But this is not the site for this question (there's `serverfault`). Search for the scp syntax.

Comment: @PaoloCasciello: destination i have mentioned i.e. /apps/configuration/

Comment: destination is in the form user@server:/path but again, look at documentation.

Comment: @RamanThakur And how the `scp` program is supposed to know **which machine** out of the several milliard ones on Earth that folder resides on?

Comment: @H2CO3 ??? in fact i told him he missed the destination. :D

Comment: @PaoloCasciello Ah sorry, that should have been directed towards OP. Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

`scp` requires a remote host name to copy to (or from). In your sample command, you didn't specify which host you're copying to, so it assumed you're doing a local copy.

Answer (score 0):

sorry, misread the question.

add "username:password@hostname:" to your command file.

scp C:\Users\karansha\Desktop\Backup\sj1slm612\express_13000\standalone-full.xml username:password@hostname:/apps/instances/express_13000/configuration/

for example: 
scp C:\Users\karansha\Desktop\Backup\sj1slm612\express_13000\standalone-full.xml karansha:karanshaspassword@karansha.com:/apps/instances/express_13000/configuration/

Answer (score 0):

In order for `scp` to understand that you want to access a remote machine, you need to specify the address for that machine.

Your current command will copy the xml file to another local file called "/apps/instances/express_13000/configuration/", if it even works at all.

```
scp C:\Users\karansha\Desktop\Backup\sj1slm612\express_13000\standalone-full.xml /apps/instances/express_13000/configuration/
```

Instead try something like this:

```
scp C:\Users\karansha\Desktop\Backup\sj1slm612\express_13000\standalone-full.xml username@10.0.1.2:/apps/instances/express_13000/configuration/
```

Of course, replace "username" with the username for that machine, and "10.0.1.2" with the actual machine IP address.

Comment: i m doing this via putty, i am already connected to remote linux machine, i think i will have to give ip and host name of my local machine in this case.

Comment: Yes, in that case you are correct. Hopefully your local machine is accessible via the remote machine. The concept is the same, just put the access information on the local address instead of the remote one. Or you could just get a file transfer client, such as FileZilla (https://filezilla-project.org/).